# How to use Chrome Tab Groups in other Chrome Windows and after restarting Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I have created a *Tab Group* called *Tsk* in one Chrome Window:

[image]

In that same Chrome Window a new tab may be added to the *Tsk* Tab Group:

[image]

However on another Chrome Window that *Tab Group* does not show as an existing Group. In particular we see the verbage "Add Tab to ***New*** Group " and not "Add Tab To Group":

[image]

Just to check I did also create a new Chrome Window : and likewise it does not "see" the existing Tab Groups.  So how do these Tab Groups get "shared" and "saved" so that they are reusable across other Windows and also if I restart Chrome altogether?